# Reading input file into abstract superclass java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class, superclass

This is my project where I have to implement inheritance, polymorphism and io.
Hope someone can assist me. I have a text file with the data of bags.

> Local;Backpack;NYC;Black;45.00;5
>  Local;Backpack;Swiss
>   Polo;Grey;59.00;1
>  Local;Backpack;Bill Keith;Blue 50.00;2
>   Import;Handbag;Padini;Yellow;120.00;3
>  Import;Handbag;PDI;Red;
>   170.00;2
>  Import;Handbag;P&CO;Green;200.00;1

I have an abstract superclass with constructor, accessor and toString method which consist of **itemType, bagType, brand, colour, price and quantity** according to the data respectively.

I also have 2 subclass, **Import and Local** which are extended from superclass bag that inherit the same attribute from superclass.

I have problem to read the data into the array of abstract superclass because it will say abstract class cannot be instantiated. Yes, I know this. So what should I do so that I can read the data into an array?

This is my abstract superclass `Bag`:

```js
public abstract class Bag
{
    private String bagType;
    private String colour;
    private String brand;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;
    
    //default constructor
    public Bag()
    {
        bagType = " ";
        colour = " ";
        brand = " ";
        quantity = 0;
        price = 0.00;
    }

    //normal constructor
    public Bag(String bagType, String brand, String colour, double price, int quantity)
    {
        this.bagType = bagType;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    //accessor method
    public String getColour()
    {
        return colour;
    }
    public String getBrand()
    {
        return brand;
    }
    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return quantity;
    }
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
    
    //mutator method
    public void setBagType(String bt)
    {
        bagType = bt;
    }
    public void setColour(String c)
    {
        colour = c;
    }
    public void setBrand(String b)
    {
        brand = b;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int q)
    {
        quantity = q;
    }
    public void setPrice(double p)
    {
        price = p;
    }

    //abstract method
    public abstract double calcPrice();

    //toString method
    public String toString()
    {
        return
        "\nBag Type      : " + bagType +
        "\nItem Colour   : " + colour +
        "\nItem Brand    : " + brand +
        "\nItem Quantity : " + quantity +
        "\nPrice         : " + price;
    }
}
```

And this is my test class:

```js
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestBag
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Bag.txt"));

            PrintWriter Import = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Import.txt")));
            PrintWriter Local = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Local.txt")));
            
            String data = null;
            int size = 0;
            while((data = in.readLine()) != null)/**read data to count the no of records*/
            {
                StringTokenizer input = new StringTokenizer(data,";");
                size++;

            }
            in.close();
            
            /**reopen the input file*/
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Bag.txt"));
            Bag b [] = new Bag[size];
            int index = 0;
            while((data = in.readLine()) != null) //read the contents of file and process the data
            {
                StringTokenizer inData = new StringTokenizer(data,";");
                
                String type = inData.nextToken();
                String bagType = inData.nextToken();
                String brand = inData.nextToken();
                String colour = inData.nextToken();
                double price = Double.parseDouble(inData.nextToken());
                int quantity = Integer.parseInt(inData.nextToken());
                
                if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Import")) //Import
                {   
                    b[index] = new Import(bagType, brand, colour, price, quantity);
                    System.out.println(b[index].toString());
                    
                }
                else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Local"))
                {
                    b[index] = new Local(bagType, brand, colour, price, quantity);
                    System.out.println(b[index].toString());
                }
                
                index++;
            }
            
            //
            
            in.close();
            Import.close();
            Local.close();
            
        }
        //end of try
        catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
        { System.out.print(fnfe.getMessage());}
        catch(IOException io)
        { System.out.print(io.getMessage());}
        catch(Exception e)
        { System.out.print(e.getMessage());}
    }

}
```

I'm sorry. I'm still new to java.

Comment: I can see no abstract class in the code you've posted.

Comment: The abstract class is in the class Bag which is the superclass, this is the class testBag where I  test my code.

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is broken, so I cannot see your `Bag` class unless you show it.

Comment: I have updated my `Bag` class

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read about abstract classes here: [Abstract Methods and Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html), also I don't see any contractors in you code... Do you have to create them by your own?

Comment: The abstract class is in the class Bag which is the superclass, this is the class testBag where I test my code. All the constructor are also on the superclass Bag and subclass Import, Local.

Answer (score -1):

If your `Bag` is abstract, then it is impossible to call `new Bag()`.

You will need to check the bagType and create a class according to it.

```
if(type.equals("import")){
   b[index] = new ImportBag (type, bagType, brand, colour, price, quantity);
} else {
   b[index] = new LocalBag (type, bagType, brand, colour, price, quantity);
}
```

An Arraylist might prove more useful than an Array.

Comment: Between your misspellings and your assumptions about what @OP has/wants, this is a substandard answer

Comment: I'm sorry for the misspellings. English is not my mothertonuge and I used my smartphone to write this. Could you tell me how I can improve my answer?

Comment: I already create the array for subclass but when I try to compile, this appear `For input string: " 5"`